# Multiple Domains SEO SSL Redirect Avoiding Loop Errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, seo

I have 4 domains in my server:

domain1.com
domain2.net
domain3.com
domain4.net

The primary and SSL enabled is: domain1.com

I try a SEO permanent 301 redirection of all of them to https://www.domain1.com and works fine, the problem is that when someone tries to access any secondary domain prefixing it with https the redirection doest work.

Example: domain2.net (or any other of those with https prefix) will not redirect to https://www.domain1.com and get a SSL certificate error.

I believe this is because SSL request uses a different port: 443 and all the Rewrite Rules i made are just for 80 port.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You get the SSL certificate error because the certificate does not match the name of the accessed server. Any redirects will only be done after establishing the SSL connection, which means you need to have a valid certificate for each domain you want to redirect from.

Comment: You mean that if all the 4 domains got a valid SSL certificate the redirection will continue to the primary domain? there is no way in a dedicated server to jump that?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with dedicated or not. The redirection is done at the HTTP level and HTTPS is HTTP inside SSL/TLS. So you need first to successfully establish the SSL/TLS connection (which includes certificate validation) before the HTTP redirect can be done.